# Is possible to do a flex layout with Qt?

Tags: qt

I want to make something like a gridlayout but the layout must decide how many elements can be fitted in a row, and when the row is full continue with the next row.
QtGridLayout also fixes the columns width.

I want to something like this (this pictures was manually organised in Horizontals and verticals grids)

[image]

When the image size changes one of the buttons goes to first row.

[image]

((In this compositions both images looks with the same size, but actually second one is wider than first one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some one answer this question but remove it, so the credits are for my unknown friend.

Qt have an example named [Flow Layout Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) for a widget based form and another for  [Graphics View widget.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-flowlayout-example.html)

[image: big width]
[image: Thin window]

Comment: Is there a pyside6/pyside2 version of it ?

Comment: @Jcyrss I know SO doesn't allow AI responses, so I won't post it, but chatGPT actually did a very good job on converting the C++ code into PySide2, had to make a few adjustents but got it working nicely. Let me know if you want a copy.